# How Do I Manipulate Shift+Enter Instead Of \n?

Tags: python, selenium

i am making a whatsapp bot for my friends birthday i want to bombard him with messages :) ,
can u please help me in solving this problem :) ?

i have tried replacing \n with \r\n but was unable to simulate shift+enter

```
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    import socket
    import time
    handl=open('message.txt','r')
    message_text=handl.read().replace('\n','\r\n')
    no_of_message=1 
    filename='contacts.txt'

    handle = open(filename,'r')

    moblie_no_list=list() # list of phone number can be of any length
    for number in handle:
        if len(number)==12:
            moblie_no_list.append(number)
        elif len(number)==13:
            moblie_no_list.append(number.replace('+',''))
        elif len(number) ==10:
            number='91'+number
            moblie_no_list.append(number)
        else:
            pass 


    def element_presence(by,xpath,time):
        element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath))
        WebDriverWait(driver, time).until(element_present)

    def is_connected():
        try:
            # connect to the host -- tells us if the host is actually
            # reachable
            socket.create_connection(("www.google.com", 80))
            return True
        except :
            is_connected()
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("http://web.whatsapp.com")
    time.sleep(10) #wait time to scan the code in second

    def send_whatsapp_msg(phone_no,text):
        driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone= 
   {}&source=&data=#".format(phone_no))
        try:
            driver.switch_to_alert().accept()
        except:
            pass

        try:
            element_presence(By.XPATH,'//* 
   [@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]',30)
            txt_box=driver.find_element(By.XPATH , '//* 
   [@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]')
            global no_of_message
            for x in range(no_of_message):
                txt_box.send_keys(text)
                txt_box.send_keys("\n")

        except :
            print("invailid phone no :"+str(phone_no))
    for moblie_no in moblie_no_list:
        try:
            send_whatsapp_msg(moblie_no,message_text)

       except Exception as e:
            time.sleep(10)
            is_connected()
```

I Expected Sending Multiline Messages But It Splits Em Into Single Message each .

Comment: Genius idea! Everyone loves being bombarded with messages. :/

Comment: he is my close friend :P ,i want to disturb him a little bit on his bday ,haha...,\nur waffle hat is cool

Comment: So you're making a spam bot? If it's your friend on his b-day, why is there a *list* of mobile numbers? Yah... you're on your own with this one.

Comment: I don't think we need to know what you are trying to do... What I don't see is where are you using the `Keys` in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
txt_box.send_keys(Keys.SHIFT,'\n')
```

## Here's What I Did To Solve The Question

- Keys.Shift Will Manipulate Press Of Shift Key Followed By '\n' Carriage Return.

  #### [Link To Complete Code On Github](https://github.com/vrushangdev/simplewhatsappbot)

### Complete Solved Code Is Here :) :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import socket
import time
handl=open('message.txt','r', encoding="utf8")
message_text=handl.read()
messages=message_text.split('\n')
print(messages)
no_of_message=1 
filename='contacts.txt'

handle = open(filename,'r')

moblie_no_list=list() # list of phone number can be of any length
for number in handle:
    if len(number)==12:
        moblie_no_list.append(number)
    elif len(number)==13:
        moblie_no_list.append(number.replace('+',''))
    elif len(number) ==10:
        number='91'+number
        moblie_no_list.append(number)
    else:
        pass 


def element_presence(by,xpath,time):
    element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath))
    WebDriverWait(driver, time).until(element_present)

def is_connected():
    try:
        # connect to the host -- tells us if the host is actually
        # reachable
        socket.create_connection(("www.google.com", 80))
        return True
    except :
        is_connected()
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://web.whatsapp.com")
time.sleep(10) #wait time to scan the code in second

def send_whatsapp_msg(phone_no,text):
    driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone={}&source=&data=#".format(phone_no))
    try:
        driver.switch_to_alert().accept()
    except:
        pass

    try:
        element_presence(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]',30)
        txt_box=driver.find_element(By.XPATH , '//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]')
        global messages
        for message in messages:
            txt_box.send_keys(message)
            txt_box.send_keys(Keys.SHIFT,'\n')
        txt_box.send_keys("\n")

    except :
        print("invailid phone no :"+str(phone_no))
for moblie_no in moblie_no_list:
    try:
        send_whatsapp_msg(moblie_no,message_text)

    except Exception as e:
        time.sleep(10)
        is_connected()
```